# Where can I put my sitemap in my directory structure under Laravel? It is 404 in the directory root

Tags: google-search-console, xml-sitemap, laravel

I'm trying to submit my sitemap on my Google console but every time I add it, it keeps saying it couldn't fetch, I have uploaded my `sitemap.xml` into my domain root directory but still Google is not seeing it. Please, how can I solve this issue, have been on this for the past two days and it's like I'm going in circles.

My sitemap is in the `public_html` folder with name `sitemap.xml`.

**UPDATE#1:** This is my directory structure:

```
/home/winnerrs
    /public_html
        /app
        /bootstrap
        /config
        /database
        /docker
        /public
        /resources
        /routes
        /storage
        .htaccess
        artisan
        composer.json
        composer.lock
        docker-compose.yml
        Dockerfile
        package.json
        phpunit.xml
        README.md
        readme.md
        robots.txt
        server.php
        sitemap.xml
        webpack.mix.js
```

**UPDATE#2:** This my `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Requesting `/sitemap.xml` from your site does result in a 404 - so you do seem to have an issue with your site? (But when you submit a sitemap to GSC, you physically upload it to Google - it doesn't need to "fetch" it?)

Comment: Thank you for your response, much appreciated but at the moment I don't know how to fix this error, I have read all through blogs they don't seems to provide solution for easy for me fix.. I'm very sure I did everything right uploading my sitemap but I don't know whatelse to fix on my GSC to get it successful. Please see my attached image here for possible solution suggest https://imgur.com/a/OSlqpuw

Comment: The problem is with your site, not GSC. How did you upload this file to your site? What web server are you using?

Comment: Thank you, I upload files to my web server through cpanel and here is information about my server in the attached image here https://imgur.com/a/8nmVSjH

Comment: Where is your `robots.txt` file located? Are you rewriting URLs to a subdirectory perhaps? (Maybe include the contents of your `.htaccess` file in your question.)

Comment: Thank you so much for time, I appreciate it. Here is an image attached of the login into my cpanel showing all files on my root directory https://imgur.com/a/wGLhOJf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having looked at your directory structure, it would seem that many (all?) files in the document root (where you have uploaded `sitemap.xml`) are not accessible - they all return 404 Not Found when accessed publicly.

It looks like this might be a Laravel app and you are perhaps rewriting everything to the `/public` subdirectory (a typical usage pattern with Laravel). In which case you should move `sitemap.xml` (and any other files that should be publicly accessible) to the `/public` subdirectory.

To confirm this, we would need to see the contents of your root `.htaccess` file. (Please edit your question to include this.)

**UPDATE:** Your `.htaccess` file confirms the above.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
> RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
> ```

From your `.htaccess` file in the document root we can see that *all* requests are rewritten to the `/public` subdirectory. So, a request for `example.com/sitemap.xml` is *internally rewritten* to `example.com/public/sitemap.xml`.

This means your document root is "*effectively*" `/home/winnerrs/public_html/public`, not `/home/winnerrs/public_html`, as you first thought.

You need to move the `sitemap.xml` file from the `public_html` directory to the `public_html/public` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, you're so correct it's a Laravel app, I'm not much of a techie, I'm just a user that manage few backend files.. But here is a look at the .htaccess files as requested here https://imgur.com/a/RQ69CRL.. Please work me through what I should probably do to fix this. Once again thank you so much

Comment: Yes, your `.htaccess` file confirms my assumption. You need to move the `sitemap.xml` file from the `public_html` directory to the `public_html/public` directory. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I so much appreciate that I found the help and you took your precious time to help out. I resubmitted and it was successful. Thank you thank you thank.